# Speakers on ASUS Zenbook UP6502Z do not work, but headphones, mic, HDMI sound work fine

Tags: sound, asus, speakers, 23.04

With Ubuntu 23.04 Settings/Sound on an Asus Zenbook Pro 15 Flip OLED, I see two output devices, 'Headphones - Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller' and 'Speaker - Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller'.

The headphones work, confirmed by 'Speaker Test', but the speaker doesn't. Everything else related to audio seems to be working (HDMI, Bluetooth, Mic). The speakers also work fine on Windows.

[alsa-info](https://pastebin.com/tVbkEL2v)